# CheckedChanged event is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my `WebForm` I want the total price changed when the user check one product but I have this problem with my code ,

the `CheckedChanged` event is not firing when I check the `CheckBox`

It is firing only when I click the `Button`(used for as clear button) , and I didn't include that code within the button event !

Here is my code:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int total = 0;
    String strtotal;

    protected void ckb1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (ckb1.Checked)
        {                
            total = total + 100;
            strtotal = total.ToString();
            lbl2.Text = strtotal;
        } 

    }

    protected void ckb2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ckb2.Checked)
        {
            total = total + 80;
            strtotal = total.ToString();
            lbl2.Text = strtotal;
        }
    }

    protected void ckb3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ckb3.Checked)
        {
            total = total + 70;
            strtotal = total.ToString();
            lbl2.Text = strtotal;
        }
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = " ";
        ckb1.Checked = false;
        ckb2.Checked = false;
        ckb3.Checked = false;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All ASP.NET Server controls except `Button`, `Hyperlink` and `LinkButton` have a default `AutoPostBack` property of `false`, So you should set  [`AutoPostBack="true"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `CheckBox`:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckb1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="ckb1_CheckedChanged" />
```

> It is firing only when I click the button

As I said this is because the `Button` have `AutoPostBack` property of `true` by default so after you checked the `CheckBox` and then click the button the `CheckBox` state automatically posts back to the server.